# In Steven Universe, what happened to Blue's human zoo after Season 4 and the Movie?

Tags: steven-universe

After *Steven Universe: The Movie* I'm unsure what happened to the "zoo" Blue Diamond kept humans in... the one she took Greg to in Season 4. Given steven's new status and all, wouldn't they have been released?

Were all those humans freed to come onto the earth, or were they kept there peacefully and of their own free will?

Does anyone know if there is a canon answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The epilogue series *Steven Universe Future*, set after the main series and the movie, is going to tie up most loose ends, including this one.

Episode 3 *"Rose Buds"* shows

> the zoo still inhabited by Holly Blue Agate, the Amethysts and the humans (and the un-bubbled Rose Quartzes).
>  Holly Blue Agate has no more authority over anyone and grumbles about the lack of order. The Amethysts spend their time relaxing with the humans, who are now free to go anywhere in the zoo and are effectively in control of the whole space station.
>  They can drive it wherever they want (in the episode they move it to the Earth to visit Steven) and nothing prevents them from leaving, but they seem to prefer staying in the ex-zoo.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any reason to believe that the zoo has significantly changed since Steven was there. The humans inside were happy and healthy, but raised to be completely dependent on their habitat and caretakers. Even if they were moved to Beach City with people who knew their situation, they'd probably still be unable to care for themselves or handle reality in any capacity. The show made it clear that they're utterly incapable of even dealing with minor sources of emotional stress, much less the real world problems that humans typically experience.

Unless Rebecca Sugar or someone else on the team clarifies differently, I think it's safe to say that the zoo is still there with the humans living in it. Abolishing it, in my opinion, would be unethical. Steven may have convinced Blue Diamond to simply stop letting them breed so that new generations aren't born and the current population eventually dies out, but that's just speculation.